# Giving each individual button it's correct name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I have a list of buttons that all need there own name. I have created a button component to reuse, but i'm not sure how to give each individual button its correct name.

```
import Button from '../../../UI/Button/Button';
import classes from './SideMenuHeader.module.css';


const SideMenuHeader = () => {
    return(
        <div className={classes.SideMenuHeader}>
            <li>32</li>
            <li><Button></Button></li> // label = project
            <li><Button></Button></li> // label = task
            <li><Button></Button></li> // label = date
            <li><Button></Button></li> // label = title
            <li><Button></Button></li> // label = newest
        </div>
    );
}

export default SideMenuHeader;

-------------
Button component

import React from 'react';
import classes from './Button.module.css';

const button = (props) => (
    <button className={classes.button}></button>
);

export default button;
```

Comment: What do you mean by name. Do you want to add a custom attribute of `name` or you just want to give each button a different label `<Button>name</Button>`

Comment: A different label @Dimensionless

Comment: go to [https://www.w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com) and familiarize yourself with html element properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
import Button from '../../../UI/Button/Button';
import classes from './SideMenuHeader.module.css';


const SideMenuHeader = () => {
  return (
    <div className={classes.SideMenuHeader}>
      <li>32</li>
      <li><Button name="project" /></li>
      <li><Button name="task" /></li>
      <li><Button name="date" /></li>
      <li><Button name="title" /></li>
      <li><Button name="newest" /></li>
    </div>
  );
}

export default SideMenuHeader;

// Button component

import React from 'react';
import classes from './Button.module.css';

const button = (props) => (
  <button className={classes.button} name={this.props.name}>{this.props.name}</button>
);

export default button;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you will do it.
Basically, you need to have an array of items that you want to render namely `items` as written in the comment of the code. Then you iterate over it using map.

I also updated the `Button` component as anything between opening and closing tag of a component is passed as `children` prop to the component, which you can use to render the encapsulated items inside the component.

```
import Button from '../../../UI/Button/Button';
import classes from './SideMenuHeader.module.css';

// items will be an array containing list
// list of all the button along with all the
// necessary options
//
// const items = [
//  { label: 'project' },
//  { label: 'task' },
//  { label: 'date' },
//  { label: 'title' },
//  { label: 'newest' },
// ]
const SideMenuHeader = ({items}) => {
    return(
        <div className={classes.SideMenuHeader}>
            <li>32</li>
            {
              items.map((item, index) => {
                return <li><Button key={index}>{ item.label }</Button></li>
              })
            }
        </div>
    );
}

export default SideMenuHeader;

-------------
Button component

import React from 'react';
import classes from './Button.module.css';

const button = ({ children }) => (
    <button className={classes.button}>{children}</button>
);

export default button;
```